# How to change modal message by clicking on link using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have a link abc and it is a external link and shows some message in modal before redirecting.

Now i have another link bca and its also a external link now i want to display different message in modal box whenever this link is clicked and this link is present all over site.

How can we do this using java script?

Comment: Add a class on that link. Add event listener with a function to that class. And in that function start a modal. For more ideas, will need more informaiton.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like this and just change the output messages ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=window.confirm("Are you sure you are ok?")
if (x)
    window.alert("Good!")
else
    window.alert("Too bad")
</script>
```